# AWS - No such bucket error when entering domain url

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I have deployed a Node app onto an Amazon EC2 instance. I then tried to point my domain to this instance. I followed the guide at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-configure-route53.html.

I created a hosted zone, entering mydomain.com.

I then created record sets for the domain and subdomain.

When creating the record for the doman, I entered the following details:

- For Type I choose "A — IPv4 address"
- For Alias I choose "Yes".
- For Alias Target the guide says "choose your root domain website endpoint from the list (for example, example.com)". However, for me, the dropdown did not have my domain. It only had "No Targets Available". I searched some forums and many people had this issue and the advice was to enter "s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com" which I did.

I did the same for subdomain, again entering "s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com".

I then went to the service where I bought the domain name and entered the name servers.

However, when i go to my URL, I get:

```
Code: NoSuchBucket
Message: The specified bucket does not exist
BucketName: mydomain.com
RequestId: 656B653A2ED5B2B1
HostId: 9etNAX1XEJmbVKUAMylBDz3xEky+7RhAnr9b8HhpkIb9+pkMnn920v/MSAUjr78oyONEUdlba50=
```

Any Ideas what Im doing wrong?

Comment: If you are using EC2 to host, S3 shiuldnt be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using EC2, you have to configure Route53 to point to the EC2, not S3. S3 is for `static` web hosting, EC2 for `dynamic`. With that said, I would highly recommend switching to EBS, it is significantly easier to point your domain to an EBS destination, otherwise there's a bit more set up. For Route53 to EC2:

1. Navigate to EC2 and hit Elastic IP
2. Register a new Elastic IP address
3. Associate this address with your instance
4. Go to instances and you should see a blue IP address hyperlink instead of a black one
5. Go back to Route53 > hosted zones > you're domain
6. Create a resource record set in your hosted zone.
7. Choose Type A – Ipv4 address.
8. For Value, specify the Elastic IP address for your Amazon EC2 instance.

Another thing, if you are using a third party vendor, all you have to do is put in the NS record (to match your Route53 ones) and the Elastic IP in the providers site. (And I would recommend swapping it to AWS, so much easier)

**Update**

@Mark also had port connection issues:

1. Navigate your `app.js` file OR `./bin/www` (if you're using `express`) and change the listening port to `80`.
2. Check your instances security group to make sure it says `incoming access: HTTP Port: 80`

This is a common mistake because developing locally does not like when you use port 80. Hence the frequent default to `3000`, `8080`, etc.

Comment: Yes, there is generally 4 of them though, also, that's generally a NodeJS specific problem. Can you include your app.js file?

Comment: Also what npm module are you using to start it?

Comment: Actually when I go to my elastic ip address on port 8080, it works. so maybe the port is the issue....

Comment: Indeed it is sir. Navigate to your app.js and switch to port 80 - to replace 8080. Also make sure your security group associated with that instance has `incoming` access for `HTTP` on port 80

Answer (score 4):

Per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/troubleshooting-s3-bucket-website-hosting.html):

> When you configure an Amazon S3 bucket for website hosting, you must give the **bucket the same name as the record** that you want to use to route traffic to the bucket. For example, if you want to **route traffic for `example.com` to an S3 bucket that is configured for website hosting, the name of the bucket must be `example.com**.

and

> If you want to route traffic to an S3 bucket that is configured for website hosting but the name of the bucket **doesn't appear in the Alias Target list** in the Amazon Route 53 console, or if you're trying to create an alias record programmatically and you're getting an InvalidInput error from the Route 53 API, one of the AWS SDKs, the AWS CLI, or AWS Tools for Windows PowerShell, check the following:
>
> - The name of the bucket exactly matches the name of the record, such as example.com or www.example.com.
> - The S3 bucket is correctly configured for website hosting. For more information, see Hosting a Static Website on Amazon S3 in the Amazon Simple Storage Service Developer Guide.